# Reverse for 'blog_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Reverse for 'blog_detail' with no arguments not found.

> Reverse for 'blog_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['blog/(?P[0-9]+)$']

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, unique=True, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1080, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/')
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    category2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField("BlogCategory")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

views.py

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    queryset =  Blog.objects.all()
    template_name = "testapp/blogd.html"
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (BlogList, BlogDetail)

urlpatterns = [

    path('blog/l', BlogList.as_view(), name='blog_list'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>', BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog_detail'),
]
```

Comment: These errors typically occur because if a misused reverse in your template.  Take a look to see if you are using the `url` template filter in the blogd.html file.

Comment: yes, you're right. i just made a mistake in my template. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you must args keyword for passing arguments in get_absolute_url method:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("blog_detail", args=[str(self.pk)])
```

Comment: providing **args is not mandatory** providing kwargs works as well and the OP already cofirmed that there was a mistake in template (check comments).