# Django NoReverseMatch :Reverse for 'blog_detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-3.0

I created a topic as a categories for blog project.
I pointed 'topic' as a PK to my model
It is successfully to access by the follow path:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/django/1
and http://127.0.0.1:8000/IDE/2 django and IDE is the topic of my model

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog, Topic
from django.views.generic import DetailView

def post_list(request, topic_slug=None):
    topic= None
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    blogs = Blog.objects.filter(available=True)
    if topic_slug:
        topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, slug=topic_slug)
        blogs = blogs.filter(topic=topic)
    return render(request,
                  'topiclist.html',
                  {'topics': topics,
                  'topic':topic,
                   'blogs': blogs,
                   })

class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name ='detail.html'
```

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import BlogDetail

urlpatterns = [
   path('<slug:topic_slug>/', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
   path('<slug:topic_slug>/<int:pk>/', BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog_detail'),
]
```

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.urls import reverse

class Topic(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, default='self.name', db_index=True, unique=True)

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'topic'
       verbose_name_plural = 'topics'

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('post:topiclist', args=[self.slug])

class Blog(models.Model):
   title =  models.CharField(max_length=50)
   author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   content = RichTextField()
   topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
   available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'post'
       verbose_name_plural  = 'posts'

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

It show the error

```
NoReverseMatch at /django/
Reverse for 'blog_detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<topic_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

when I use the the URL config of
 `blog_detail`

```
My HTML template
{% block content %}
 {% for blog in blogs %}
<a href="{% url 'blog_detail' blog.pk %}">{{ topic.title }}</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

It works for using `post_list` but when I am using `blog_detail` it show the error. Any idea for this? I am new for django and programming. so many thanks if anyone could help. I read this question but it not help 
[Reverse for 'blog_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59938995/reverse-for-blog-detail-with-no-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-tried-blo)

Comment: It expects a slug as first parameter, the `topic_slug`.

Comment: still not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your urls.py code, the `blog_detail` url requires two arguments (the topic slug and the pk) and you only supplied the pk. If you pass in both, it should work (or refactor the url so the topic slug is not required).

`{% url 'blog_detail' blog.topic.slug blog.pk %}`